# ssh access denied via ipv4 but normal access via ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ipv6, ipv4

I'm running Ubuntu 19 or 20 (both scenarios same)

I can ping and ssh over ipv4 to my server.

When i ssh it over ip4 it even asks for the username and password but denies access and shows "access denied"

But when i ssh over ipv6 i can login with the same username and password.

I have the least idea what maybe going wrong, even tried small passwords such as "1" but access denied.

ip addr shows (real ip i have scrambled) -

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:de:48:be:38:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 161.253.189.186/24 brd 162.250.189.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2601:ffd3:1:24e::1/36 scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::8de:48ff:febe:38e5/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: If you want our help you will have to provide the us your OpenSSH Server configuration file.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually SSHing _to your server?_ Is the IP address shown in `ip addr`? Does the server have any mention of your IPv4 login attempts in `journalctl -f`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what reason the dns was broken on a new installation and for that (wth???) reason it denied access over ipv4.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406827/how-to-set-dns-on-ubuntu-22-04-when-you-have-no-netplan-config) resolved the dns and then ipv4 access was working, very very strange.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406827/how-to-set-dns-on-ubuntu-22-04-when-you-have-no-netplan-config

Create a file:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf
```

Add my dns in this file:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Then restart systemd-resolved

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Comment: Link only answers get deleted.  Please post the essentials here, so that your answer is useful top future visitors.